# WiseCustomCalla.dll ? What is that?

Tags: windows, dll

I have a few folders in my Windows folder (I'm running Windows 7) like this:
C:\Windows\1C4551A64743409391E41477CD655043.TMP\WiseCustomCalla.dll

All they contain is WiseCustomCalla.dll. I've read that it is part of McAfee antivirus or whatever. The problem is: I have **never ever** installed any antivirus software on my machine.

What is this file and what is it doing on my machine?

I am also using Steam and PunkBuster if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This DLL is part of the [Wise Installer](http://www.symantec.com/business/package-studio) as far as I know. Some programs aren't particularly good about removing the temporary files they create; it's really nothing to worry about. And by the way, you should install some [antivirus](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) software; you never think you need it until you get bit :)

Answer (score 0):

From reading around about this dll, it seems a part of McAfee Config utility. So my hunch is that it is used by an installer (possibly the Steam installer) to configure your anti-virus software so it can get online (that's why you have to run the Steam installer with administrative rights).

Beware, there is also spyware out there who also installs and uses this dll (for the same purpose... to get online). So it might come from there as well.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that `WiseCustomCall.dll/WiseCustomcalla.dll` comes from the Enigma Software Group who are the makers of Spy Hunter 4. This is an anti malware program to be avoided at all costs as it does not have a free trial period and can cause untold damage to your computer or other device.

You can do as free scan of your computer/device but have to pay a fee for removal of found malware/viruses without knowing what it will do to your computer or other device.

Research has found that it will black screen/blue screen your computer/device as per other comments about this product. I researched this on BLEEPING COMPUTER, a site which is used by very reputable computer technicians, so it is worthwhile fully researching an anti malware/ anti virus program before you download it.

I have spoken with some top computer technicians who say that this "virus/malware" may be permanently embedded in my hard drive and may be very hard to get rid of. Hopefully Revo Uninstaller's Evidence Remover tool will fully delete it. No other anti virus/anti malware program will find it as it was thought to be a normal Windows operating system by them and found by me in 2 WINDOWS files on my main hard drive "C" that just had some strange numbers.

I only found 5 traces in 1 file and 7 in the other. I deleted all traces and then the numbered files from the Windows file, then tried systems recovery which brought it all back. I deleted these files again and am currently running Revo Uninstaller's Evidence Remover tool which will hopefully fully delete this virus.

I never thought for 1 moment that a virus/ malware would piggyback itself into my computer from a supposedly reputable and secure site which markets a supposedly reputable anti malware program. I suspect that this virus/malware could also be the cause of CouponBar recurring on my computer.

Comment: Any evidence it's *only* used by that program, rather than just *any* program that uses the Wise installer? The above just sounds like an unrelated rant to me.

Comment: According to Bleeping Computer (the site you gave as your source) Spy Hunter is no longer considered a rogue application (http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/uninstall/3307/SpyHunter.html)