# What are these hexadecimal .tmp folders in my windows root containing WiseCustomCalla dlls?

Tags: windows

A few minutes ago, i went browsing through my Windows folder to find the proper name of my flash version for http://decentsecurity.com/enterprise/#/flash-force-update/. In my Windows root, I found 3 folders that were named with a rather long hexadecimal string ending in .tmp, each folder containing a DLL called `WiseCustomCalla.dll`. I tried to google this and depending on where I look, this file has been labeled as part of malware, part of software for anonymous browsing, part of antivirus software (often labeled as McAfee which I don't use, but I have also found references to Norton, which I use myself),....

I don't trust these files to be honest, but I'd rather not delete them if they're actually important.

Are they important, or can I safely delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question has been answered over at SuperUser, and is probably better suited there.](https://superuser.com/questions/136312/wisecustomcalla-dll-what-is-that)

To quote the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/136532):

> This DLL is part of the [Wise Installer](http://www.symantec.com/business/package-studio) as far as I know. Some programs aren't particularly good about removing the temporary files they create; it's really nothing to worry about.

Note that the link in the accepted answer is broken. Wise Installer is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Solutions,_Inc.):

> (...) one of the most widely used installation packages for Windows.

So you can safely remove the folders, seeing that the dlls are only used for installing software, and not properly deleting the temporary files afterwards.